# How do you enable cookies with the newest IOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I was playing Pokémon go and for some reason it's signed me out and I had to log in again, it wouldn't let me play it because I haven't enabled cookies! I tried and tried but nothing would work,YouTube(Failed),settings(Nothing), asking the company(noresponse).nothing would work so I had to make a new account. Now the same thing has happend and I need help on how to enable cookies for my game to work! Please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has an answer on Arqade SE: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/278248/105931

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Unfortunately closing as duplicate doesn't work cross-site.

Comment: I didn't know how to flag for migration 

Answer (score 1):

Taken from https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/278248/105931

> Here's what I did that worked for me. Might not even need to do what I did...
>
> 1. Iphone > Settings > Safari > Block Cookies > Always Allow
> 2. Open Safari > Gmail.com > Logon with your gmail account > Open
>      Pokemon Go
>
> [More information about this issue from niantic itself](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/224047008)